# Can I use a Python module stored in a GCS bucket inside my Docker image?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have a Docker image in GCP run in a GKE pod. I instantiate the whole image using Airflow and the `GKEPodOperator`.

My Python script uses a `parameters.py` module which holds some variables, kind of configuration.
This is currently stored in a GCS bucket and I can pass its gcs file path using the Airflow operator mentioned above.

My question is how can I make the image use this file as a module then?

I tried inside the Python script:

```
sys.path.append(BUCKET_PATH/parameters.py)
import parameters
```

but it didn't seem to recognise it. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: How does your Dockerfile look like?

To access Cloud Storage from your image, you could simply use the [client library](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries).

Comment: In a [Python container](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/), you should add "pip install gcloud" to requirements.txt.